# GeoServer GSR Extension - ESRI Rest Services

Tags: geoserver, feature-service, extensions

Is anyone using this extension in 2023? Is it rock solid stable? We would like to add it to our GeoServer but are concerned to affect the stability.

Comment: We are still evaluating the GSR extensions, it looks promising. But it also has some weird issues that we are facing, For example the WFS service says geometry type is Point but GSR is saying its Polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a [community module](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/community/index.html) which means that there is no regular maintainer support.

> Community modules are considered “pending” in that they are not officially part of the GeoServer releases. They are however built along with the nightly builds, so you can download and play with them.

If you intend to use it in a production environment you would probably want to step forward as [maintainers for the module](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/policies/community-modules.html#promoting-a-community-module) or [pay some one to do that for you](https://geoserver.org/support/).